# coreldraw vba find text in cell and add description in same row

Tags: vba, cells, coreldraw

I have a library with symbols named 01-XXXX each with a specific description.
I placed a table in my page and i'd like to be able to match the text in cell(1,1) with a symbol name and add the description of the symbol in cell (1,2) and how many instances of that symbol were used in cell (1,3) and so on for the rest of the rows in that table.
heres my code:

```
Dim s As Shape
Dim toFind As String

toFind = "01-"
For Each s In ActiveDocument.ActivePage.Shapes
    If s.Type = cdrTextShape Then
         If InStr(1, s.Text.Story, toFind) > 0 Then
         'add symbols description in same row, column 2
         'count how many instances of the symbol were used in the page
         CountFind = CountFind + 1
         End If
   End If
 Next

End If
End Sub
```

I cannot find any references on how to locate and manipulate a cell in a table in coreldraw.
Any suggestions?

Comment: does coreldraw VBA editor have a Watch window?

Comment: this works in msWord. may work in coreldraw. `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(1).Range.Text`   `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(1).Range` is the cell content object   ... this also works `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text` , probably better ... `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1).Width = 40`

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  No, that is not recognized by CorelDraw :(

Comment: is there a watch window available?